# How to use Terraform provisioner with multiple instances

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I want to create x instances and run the same provisioner.

```
resource "aws_instance" "workers" {
  ami = "ami-08d658f84a6d84a80"
  count = 3
  ...
```

```
provisioner "remote-exec" {
    scripts = ["setup-base.sh", "./setup-docker.sh"]
    connection {
      type = "ssh"
      host = "${element(aws_instance.workers.*.public_ip, count.index)}"
      user = "ubuntu"
      private_key = file("${var.provisionKeyPath}")
      agent = false
    }
  }
```

I think the `host` line confuses Terraform. Getting `Error: Cycle: aws_instance.workers[2], aws_instance.workers[1], aws_instance.workers[0]`

Comment: Is that provisioner part of the `aws_instance.workers` resource? It's pretty hard to tell from what you've included in the question right now so an edit to clarify that would be useful.

Comment: Happy to provide more information if you could let me know wha you're missing.

Comment: Can you include the full Terraform config please? In general it's best to provide a [mcve] so that people can reproduce your issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since I upgrade my terraform version(0.12), I have been encountered the same problem as yours.

You need to use `${self.private_ip}` for the `host` property in your `connection` object,
and the `connection` object should be located out of the `provisioner "remote-exec"`

Details are the below.

```
resource "aws_instance" "workers" {
  ami = "ami-08d658f84a6d84a80"
  count = 3
  ...
  connection {
    host = "${self.private_ip}"
    type = "ssh"
    user = "YOUR_USER_NAME"
    private_key = "${file("~/YOUR_PEM_FILE.pem")}"
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    scripts = ["setup-base.sh", "./setup-docker.sh"]
  }
...
}
```

If you need to get more information, the below link is gonna be helping you.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/20286